# How to get GPS location instantly in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, navigation, gps, location, xamarin.forms

I am capturing the Latitude & Longitude on `Listview_ItemTapped` by using the `Geolocator` plugin to get GPS Location in xamarin.forms.
But takes average more than 15 second to capture location. Is there any way to get location instantly.

```
if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled == false)
 {
    await DisplayAlert("Notification", "Geolocation is Unavailable ", "Ok");
 }
 else
 {
    Application.Current.Properties["LATITUDE"] = null;
     Application.Current.Properties["LONGITUDE"] = null;

    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    //locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;               
    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 50000);

    Application.Current.Properties["LATITUDE"] = position.Latitude;
    Application.Current.Properties["LONGITUDE"] = position.Longitude;

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new RetailerDetailsPage(), false);
 }
```

I tried by removing `locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;` but again sometime it works instantly & sometime its not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can get a quicker response, but it *depends* on your requirements.

The long answer involves understanding that each device OS & model, the accuracy requested, the GPS acquisition time, your current physical environment (indoors, outdoor, physical shading of GPS satellites, ...), etc... all effect how long it takes to get a full GPS response back.

While the Xamarin.Plugin `Geolocator` is great and I use it all the time, it does not provide access to all the various platform-specific location features.

On **iOS** you could use the `RequestLocation` on CoreLocation which Apple describes as "a quick fix" on the user's location. This will perform the fastest GPS power up, acquire and power down that is available. It is great for getting that quick one-shot location.

On **Android** you could use Google's Play FusedLocationProviderApi (`FusedLocationApi`) and grab the users location via `GetLastLocation`. This will return the location immediately (with a small chance that it might be null).

Using Google location service, you can get a location based upon just the user's wifi connection (SSID-based), etc...

So via using a Forms' platform-specific [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/), you can obtain a quick location and then use Xamarin.Plugin's `Geolocator` to obtain a more accurate and/or more recent location.

This is exactly what we do on an background thread in an app at startup startup time as the first view that the user sees is their location on a custom map, than when an a "full" GPS location is obtained from the background thread (and possibly more accurate location) we can adjust the map...

Comment: Thanks @SushilHangover But here in my case I need the quick & accurate location where the user will probably in outdoor environment. I just need the accurate Latitude & Longitude, which confirms use's visit to that location. I am not going to display user's location on Map. also mostly user will be remote location which does not guarantee on the good wifi or internet connectivity. So which is the best and simple way to implement this ?

Comment: @GaneshParikh In your case you need to rely on a full GPS location and that is only going to happen as fast as the device/model responses to the request. So you either continue to do it like you are, or you start checking the user's GPS location in the background **before** the user taps the ListView and thus when they do you already have a cached Long/Lat available and you stop your background GPS updates